# Invoking getSelectedRow method on does not return consistent results

Tags: java, swing, jtable

My JTable has couple of rows listed. For the first time when i invoke getselectedRow() it gives me the correct result but after that it always returns me -1.

After the first call to getSelectedRow() I am deleting the selected row and then I am trying to refresh the table and that's what seems to be causing this issue. If i remove the code for refreshing the table it works fine again.

For refreshing the table, first i invoke

```
model.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
```

and after that I rebuild the table as i would for the first time i.e. hitting the database and inserting rows into model.

Any suggestions what I need to do?

Comment: After you insert the rows back into the model, are you calling `setRowSelectionInterval()` or anything else to get a row selected?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @RobI Currently I am not doing any thing of this sort, Is it advisable to do so?

Comment: What is `removeAllElements()`?

Comment: @Bala clearing the table will deselect all rows; if you want them selected after that, either the user needs to select them or your code nerds to select them using that method or the odel.

Answer (score 3):

> For the first time when i invoke getselectedRow() it gives me the correct result but after that it always returns me -1.

this is possible only in the case that

- isn't any row selected
- JTable is empty

you have to test `if (table.getSelectedRow() != -1) {`  before code execution

Comment: This is a good suggestion :-), this will also give a good testing ground, as to where the fault lies.

Comment: I am already doing this stuff and also both the possibilities mentioned above don't hold, Table is not empty as I am able to see the rows after removing from table and I am selecting the row do doubt about that.

Comment: JTable and its events must be called from EDT, what9s happens when you hardcode data for TableModel, remove that by using your standard code, set the delay from Swing Timer and add data back form hardcoded data to to Model back, events Swing Timer reduce any of EDT lack